# Removing extra space with \pmod command

Tags: spacing, subscripts

When using the \pmod command as a subscript to a sum, I often encounter some extra unwanted space.  For example, writing

```
\[ \sum_{n \equiv 1 \pmod{k}} ... \]
```

produces the following image:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas to delete the extra white space between the 1 and the open parenthesis?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd define a variant of `\pmod`:

```
\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy\@@pmod\pmod
\DeclareRobustCommand{\pmod}{\@ifstar\@pmods\@@pmod}
\def\@pmods#1{\mkern4mu({\operator@font mod}\mkern 6mu#1)}
\makeatother
```

You can use `\pmod` as before in all other situations and write

```
\[ \sum_{n \equiv 1 \pmod*{k}} ... \]
```

when you need it as a subscript to a sum.

[image]

Another way might be to load `amsmath` and redefine `\pod` (`\pmod` is defined in terms of it):

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\pod}[1]{\allowbreak\mathchoice
  {\if@display \mkern 18mu\else \mkern 8mu\fi (#1)}
  {\if@display \mkern 18mu\else \mkern 8mu\fi (#1)}
  {\mkern4mu(#1)}
  {\mkern4mu(#1)}
}
```

This will avoid having to say `\pmod*` and the result will be the same as shown.

<sub>The original answer had `\let\@@pmod\pmod`, which worked at the time the answer was written, but later `\pmod` became a robust command.</sub>

Comment: egreg, shouldn't the `\allowbreak` go before the `\mathchoice`? I was just looking at your comment on Andrew Swann's answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255584/errors-in-arguments-when-renewing-mod-with-mathchoice

Comment: @justin You're perfectly right!

Comment: @egreg -- not sure why this one came up on my screen, but it did; `\pod` is already defined in `amsmath`, although i think it's not often used.  however, the `*` version of `\pmod` is a good idea, and i've added it to the list of requests.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
\newcommand{\congruence}[3]{\ensuremath{{#1}\equiv {#2}\left(\bmod{#3}\right)}\xspace}
```

Then use it like so ...

```
\congruence{a}{b}{m}
```

Comment: Hmmm, [that does not look good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adLmM.png), even compared to the original `\pmod` usage.