# Writing mod in congruence problems without leading space

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I have been writing

```
$a \equiv r (\mod n)$
```

but this puts a space between the `(` and `mod`. For example,  `r  ( mod n )` instead of `r (mod n)`. So, how do you write `r (\mod n)` without that space?  What would be the correct way to write `$a \equiv r (\mod n)$`?

Comment: You should use `\pmod` (from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)), perhaps utilizing the redefinition as in [Removing extra space with `\pmod` command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39221/5764).

Comment: and if one drops parentheses, `\bmod` also from `amsmath` is an option.

Answer (score 115):

The spacing issue is an obvious indication that it's not meant to be used that way. However, you could wing your own, depending on the sophistication you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\ (\mathrm{mod}\ #1)}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a &\equiv r \mod n \\
  a &\equiv r \pmod{n} \\
  a &\equiv r \Mod{n}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great! I like how \Mod{n} looks. The only problem I'm encountering with \Mod{n} is that the "mod" becomes italicized in theorem/lemma/example/proof/etc. environments.

Comment: @Mathemanic: You can try using `\textup` (or perhaps `\mbox`) instead of `\text`.

Comment: This should be `\mathrm{mod}`.

Comment: @egreg why is it `\mathrm` over `\operatorname`?

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Because this is not an operator.

Comment: What is the obvious way that it is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 38):

I think `$a \equiv r \;(\bmod\; n)$` does what you want (as mentioned by jfbu in the comment).

Answer (score 11):

Both the latex kernel and `amsmath` provide the command `\pmod`.  In the latex kernel `\pmod` provides a fixed amount of space before `(mod ...)`.  The `amsmath` version is slightly more sophisticated, using a smaller amount of space when not in a display.  So one way is to define a new command that temporarily switches off the display mode:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tpmod}[1]{{\@displayfalse\pmod{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tpmod}[1]{{\@displayfalse\pmod{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text (no change): \( a\tpmod{b} \) vs.\ \( c\pmod{d} \).

Display:
\begin{gather*}
  a\tpmod{b} \\
  \intertext{vs.}
  c\pmod{d}.
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue can easily be handled by using `\pmod`.