# Is it just me or $f(x) = x^2 + 17 \mod 43$ adds too much space before the mod operator?

Tags: spacing, amsmath

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Instead of $f(x) = x^2 + 17 \mod 43$, I prefer $f(x) = x^2 + 17\hspace{-1mm}\mod 43$.  

\end{document}
```

**Why was the modulo operator defined with this apparent extra space?  Is there a rationale behind it?**

I'm on the brink of redefining it.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Writing mod in congruence problems without leading space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137073/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost: it is not an “operator”, but a traditional way to write a particular equivalence relation. Also the correct syntax is `\mod{43}`.

Plain TeX only has `\pmod`, defined as

```
% plain.tex, line 1089
\def\pmod#1{\allowbreak\mkern18mu({\rm mod}\,\,#1)}
```

so the space is 1em (in the math symbol font), because 18mu is 1em.

In the LaTeX kernel the definition is essentially the same, namely

```
% latex.ltx, line 4437:
\def\pmod#1{%
  \allowbreak\mkern18mu({\operator@font mod}\,\,#1)}
```

On the other hand, `amsmath` also defines `\mod` and `\pod`. The former omits parentheses and the latter has parentheses but no “mod”.

```
\newcommand{\pod}[1]{\allowbreak
  \if@display\mkern18mu\else\mkern8mu\fi(#1)}
\renewcommand{\pmod}[1]{\pod{{\operator@font mod}\mkern6mu#1}}
\newcommand{\mod}[1]{\allowbreak\if@display\mkern18mu
  \else\mkern12mu\fi{\operator@font mod}\,\,#1}
```

The definition of `\pmod` is in terms of `\pod`; you can see that `a\equiv b\pod{n}` will have, after *b*, 1em of space in display style or 8/18em in other styles, followed by (*n*). With `\pmod` the spacing before the parenthesis is the same, but after the parentheses “mod” and a space of 6/18em will precede *n*.

With `\mod` the spacing is essentially the same, but 12/18em would be used instead of 8/18em in text style or below. Note that `\,\,` is the same as `\mkern 6mu`.

So it's just you. `;-)`

Of course you're free to change the spacing by redefining `\pod` and `\mod`.

Comment: It's great that you prove your comments by showing the original definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The even spaced version is `\bmod` as in Sebastiano's now deleted answer which has the spacing you seem to want but is the wrong thing here as it would mean x^2 + (17 mod 43) which is the wrong interpretation. You want the bigger space before mod to separate it from the 17 and make it clear that it's a side condition applying to the equality which is to be interpreted as a congruence mod 43.