# How to reduce space between $n\equiv 1\pmod{4}$

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I ran the following code and got the following huge space when using `\pmod` function. 
It is looking odd in the paper. Could anyone suggest how to reduce space?

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
    MSC(C_n^2) &=& \begin{cases}
           1, & \text{if $n$ is odd and d is even ($n\equiv 1\pmod{4}$)},\\
           2, & \mbox{if n is even and d is even ($n\equiv 0\pmod {4}$)},\\
           3, & \mbox{if n is odd and d is odd ($n\equiv 3\pmod {4}$)},\\
           3, & \mbox{if n is even and d is odd ($n\equiv 2\pmod {4}$)}.
           \end{cases}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated you should not use `eqnarray*` which produces bad spacing at the alignment points. Use one of the `amsmath`  environments instead (`align*` or `alignat*`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [Writing mod in congruence problems without leading space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137073/5764), use `\Mod` as defined below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\ (\mathrm{mod}\ #1)}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  MSC(C_n^2) &= 
    \begin{cases}
      1, & \text{if $n$ is odd and $d$ is even ($n \equiv 1 \Mod{4}$)},  \\
      2, & \text{if $n$ is even and $d$ is even ($n \equiv 0 \Mod{4}$)}, \\
      3, & \text{if $n$ is odd and $d$ is odd ($n \equiv 3 \Mod{4}$)},   \\
      3, & \text{if $n$ is even and $d$ is odd ($n \equiv 2 \Mod{4}$)}.
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped.

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the italic font, the display is inside a theorem statement.

I would avoid the parentheses and the repetition of common parts:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\DeclareMathOperator{\MSC}{MSC}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Blah, blah
\begin{equation*}
\MSC(C_n^2)=
\begin{cases}
  1, & \text{if $n$ is odd and $d$ is even, i.e., $n\equiv 1$},\\
  2, & \text{if $n$ is even and $d$ is even, i.e., $n\equiv 0$},\\
  3, & \text{if $n$ is odd and $d$ is odd, i.e., $n\equiv 3$},\\
  3, & \text{if $n$ is even and $d$ is odd, i.e., $n\equiv 2$},
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where congruences are modulo~$4$.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Some notes:

1. “MSC” should be upright and treated as an operator;
2. even in the context of italic font, math variables should be input in math mode;
3. `eqnarray` is not to be used when `amsmath` is available (and it should be loaded whenever a document has serious math in it;
4. use the proper environment, in this case `equation*` because you don't have an alignment.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The LaTeX kernel borrows its definition of `\pmod`

```
\def\pmod#1{%
  \allowbreak\mkern18mu({\operator@font mod}\,\,#1)}
```

(see `ltmath.dtx`, code lines 39–40) from plain TeX, in which it reads

```
\def\pmod#1{\allowbreak\mkern18mu({\rm mod}\,\,#1)}
```

(see *The TeXbook*, p. 361); in both cases, the space that precedes the word “mod” is 1em wide.  The examples of use given on p. 164 of *The TeXbook*, as well as the answer to Exercise 18.4, show that Knuth intended that that amount of space ought to be used also in in-line math formulas.  Nonetheless, the `amsmath` package modifies the above definition in such a way that a narrower space is employed when the formula is “not displayed”:

```
\newcommand{\pod}[1]{\allowbreak
  \if@display\mkern18mu\else\mkern8mu\fi(#1)}
\renewcommand{\pmod}[1]{\pod{{\operator@font mod}\mkern6mu#1}}
```

(see also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357639/69818) to [Writing mod in congruence problems without leading space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137073/69818), a question already linked from [the accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504140/69818) to this question).  As you can see, the condition of “not being in display” is detected through the `\if@display` switch.

Musing over this question, I began to wonder whether this could be a bug—or rather, a design flaw—in the package.  Perhaps a better idea would be to have the amount of space change with the current math style, in a fashion similar to the way in which “big operator” symbols like `\sum` or `\int` change their size (and, to some extent, their shape) between display and non-display math.  This behavior is easily achieved with the patch to the `\pod` command (defined by the `amsmath` package) that the following code shows:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

% \usepackage{amsmath} % Required for what follows; but...
\usepackage{mathtools} % ... "mathtools" automatically loads "amsmath".

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*\pod[1]{%
  \allowbreak
  \mathchoice
    {\mkern 18mu}%
    {\mkern  8mu}%
    {\mkern  8mu}%
    {\mkern  8mu}%
  (#1)%
}

\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}



\begin{document}

In-line: \( 5\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \).  In display:
\[ 5\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \]
Non-display inside display:
\[
    f(x) =
        \begin{cases}
            4 & \mbox{if $x\equiv 0 \pmod 4$,} \\
            x\bmod 4 & \mbox{otherwise.}
        \end{cases}
\]
The same thing, but with \texttt{cases*} (requires \textsf{mathtools}):
\[
    f(x) =
        \begin{cases*}
            4 & if $x\equiv 0 \pmod 4$, \\
            x\bmod 4 & otherwise.
        \end{cases*}
\]

\begin{thm}
    All over again.
    In-line: \( 5\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \).  In display:
    \[ 5\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \]
    Non-display inside display:
    \[
        f(x) =
            \begin{cases}
                4 & \mbox{if $x\equiv 0 \pmod 4$,} \\
                x\bmod 4 & \mbox{otherwise.}
            \end{cases}
    \]
    With \texttt{cases*}:
    \[
        f(x) =
            \begin{cases*}
                4 & if $x\equiv 0 \pmod 4$, \\
                x\bmod 4 & otherwise.
            \end{cases*}
    \]
\end{thm}

Nonetheless, inside an alignment, say
\begin{align*}
    2 &\equiv 9 \pmod 7 \\
    4 &\equiv 1 \pmod 3 \mbox{,}
\end{align*}
the output agrees with that of a displayed equation:
\[
    5\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \mbox{.}
\]

\end{document}
```

This is the output the above code yields:

[image: Output of the code]

This modification could be an elegant and consistent way of achieving what the question asks for.  If the `\mod` command is used as well, it should be similarly modified too.  Of course, one can’t introduce these changes in the code of `masmath` package without disrupting all existing documents that use these features…

---

**Addition:**
Continuing to chew over this issue, I thought that it could even make sense to use the `\pmod` command in super/subscripts (see example below); and in this case, it seems that the space before the left parenthesis should be made even thinner.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

% \usepackage{amsmath} % Required for what follows; but...
\usepackage{mathtools} % ... "mathtools" automatically loads "amsmath".

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*\pod[1]{%
  \allowbreak
  \mathchoice
    {\mkern 18mu}%
    {\mkern  8mu}%
    {\mkern  6mu}% "6mu" matches the space *after* the word "mod"
    {\mkern  6mu}%
  (#1)%
}

\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}



\begin{document}

In-line: \( 5\equiv 1 \pmod{4} \).  In display:
\[ 5\equiv 1 \pmod{4} \]
Non-display inside display:
\[
    f(x) =
        \begin{cases}
            4 & \mbox{if $x\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$,} \\
            x\bmod 4 & \mbox{otherwise.}
        \end{cases}
\]
The same thing, but with \texttt{cases*} (requires \textsf{mathtools}):
\[
    f(x) =
        \begin{cases*}
            4 & if $x\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$, \\
            x\bmod 4 & otherwise.
        \end{cases*}
\]

\begin{thm}
    All over again.
    In-line: \( 5\equiv 1 \pmod{4} \).  In display:
    \[ 5\equiv 1 \pmod{4} \]
    Non-display inside display:
    \[
        f(x) =
            \begin{cases}
                4 & \mbox{if $x\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$,} \\
                x\bmod 4 & \mbox{otherwise.}
            \end{cases}
    \]
    With \texttt{cases*}:
    \[
        f(x) =
            \begin{cases*}
                4 & if $x\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$, \\
                x\bmod 4 & otherwise.
            \end{cases*}
    \]
\end{thm}

Nonetheless, inside an alignment, say
\begin{align*}
    2 &\equiv 9 \pmod{7} \\
    4 &\equiv 1 \pmod{3} \mbox{,}
\end{align*}
the output agrees with that of a displayed equation:
\[
    5\equiv 1 \pmod{4} \mbox{.}
\]

In super\slash subscripts:
\[
    \int_{0}^{3\pi} \sin x\,dx
        = -\cos x \biggr|_{0}^{3\pi}
        = -\cos x \biggr|_{x\equiv 0 \pmod{2\pi}}^{x\equiv 3\pi \pmod{2\pi}}
        = -\cos x \biggr|_{0}^{\pi}
        = 1-(-1) = 2
\]

\end{document}
```

The output in this second case is

[image: Output of the second code sample]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think using `\pmod` within parentheses looks so nice, especially if the outer (text) parentheses are italic, so I propose using `\bmod` instead.  I propose two ways: with the `cases*` environment from `mathtools (simpler syntax), and with a standard`cases`,and`eqparbox` to align the modulus conditions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  MSC(C_n^2) &=
    \begin{cases}
       1, &  \eqparbox{CN}{if $n$ is odd and $d$ is even} (n \equiv 1 \bmod{4}), \\
       2, &  \eqparbox{CN}{if $n$ is even and $d$ is even\enspace} (n \equiv 0 \bmod{4}), \\
       3, &  \eqparbox{CN}{ if $n$ is odd and $d$ is odd}  (n \equiv 3 \bmod{4}), \\
       3, & \eqparbox{CN}{ if $n$ is even and $d$ is odd } (n \equiv 2 \bmod{4}).
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  MSC(C_n^2) &=
    \begin{cases*}
      1, & if $n$ is odd and $d$ is even ($n \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$), \\
      2, & if $n$ is even and $d$ is even ($n \equiv 0 \bmod{4}$), \\
      3, & if $n$ is odd and $d$ is odd ($n \equiv 3 \bmod{4}$), \\
      3, & if $n$ is even and $d$ is odd ($n \equiv 2 \bmod{4}$).
    \end{cases*}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]