# How to write the congruence modulo n symbol?

Tags: math-mode

When a is the remainder when b is divided by n, we say b is congruent to a mod n.

How is it typeset using LaTeX?

Comment: `b\equiv a\pmod{n}`

Comment: You also have `b\equiv a \mod{n}` (no parentheses, same spacing) or `b\equiv a \bmod{n}` (no parentheses, smaller spacing).  All this is explained in the  `amsmath` documentation.

Comment: Related: [Writing mod in congruence problems without leading space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137073)

Comment: There are many notations for congruence of integers modulo an integer, and there are good reasons for using different ones in different situations. See https://github.com/Ben-McKay/concrete-algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pmod n`. It is known to work.

Comment: It would be clearer if you wrote out a more complete example, like $n \equiv 1 \pmod{k}$.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways, choose the one you prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % just to make the lines spread out

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\verb|$a\equiv b \pmod{n}$| & $a\equiv b \pmod{n}$ \\
\verb|$a\equiv b \mod{n}$|  & $a\equiv b \mod{n}$ \\
\verb|$a\equiv b \pod{n}$|  & $a\equiv b \pod{n}$ \\
\verb|$a\equiv b \bmod{n}$| & $a\equiv b \bmod{n}$ & (wrong)
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

***Don't forget*** the braces: try `a\equiv b \pmod 11` or `a\equiv b \pmod pq` and see why.

The last one is marked “wrong”, because the usage is improper: `\bmod` should be used for the “modulo” binary operation (the one that is often denoted by `%` in computing).