# Why is there extra space prefixing the first case

Tags: math-mode, align, cases

I don't understand why there is extra space before the mod in this formula.
How can I force the `m` and the `0` to be aligned vertically?

[image]

Here is the LaTeX code I'm using.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  f(x)&=\begin{cases}
  \mod(x  , 3) &\text{; if } x \neq 0\\
  0&\text{; if } x = 0
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Here's a [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137073/writing-mod-in-congruence-problems-without-leading-space) to a similar question with the suggested `\bmod` macro in comments.

Comment: As Celdor mentions there are several constructions for `mod`, the one you're using here always assumes it comes after something, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Celdor No, `\bmod` is not the right tool.

Comment: Why you don't use ```\text{mod}```? I think it's useful in this case.

Answer (score 2):

For such usage you want to do

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\opmod}{mod}% mod as operator
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\opmod}{mod}% mod as operator

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  f(x)&=\begin{cases}
  \opmod(x, 3) &\text{; if } x \neq 0\\
  0            &\text{; if } x = 0
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd remove the semicolons.

Why not `\bmod`? Compare the result of

```
6\bmod(x,3)
```

with

```
6\opmod(x,3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `\bmod` does the trick.  as pointed out by daleif, `\mod` assumes there is space before it.