# Errors in arguments when renewing \mod with \mathchoice

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Currently I am using the `\mod` command that comes with `amsmath`, and while I'm in general satisfied with it, I didn't like the way it handles spacing in text style.

I tried to renew the `\mod` command as follows:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\mod}[1]{\mathchoice
  {\allowbreak \if@display \mkern 18mu\else \mkern 5mu\fi
    {\operator@font mod} \mkern 6mu #1}
  {\allowbreak \if@display \mkern 18mu\else \mkern 5mu\fi
    {\operator@font mod} \mkern 6mu #1}
  {\mkern4mu {\operator@font mod} \mkern 6mu #1}
  {\mkern4mu {\operator@font mod} \mkern 6mu #1}
}
\makeatother
```

Now I get all kinds of errors if I type `\mod \mathfrak p`, and in order to avoid these errors I have to type `\mod {\mathfrak p}`. However, before I renewed the command, it was fine to type `\mod \mathfrak p` and this produced no errors. Is there a way I could fix this, or should I just stick to typing `\mod {\mathfrak p}`?

Comment: you are aware that `amsmath` provide four `\mod` macros?

Comment: The correct syntax should be `\mod{\mathfrak{p}}` anyway. Notice that the `\allowbreak` you have in your definition will do nothing, because it sits inside a subformula; put it before `\mathchoice`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mimic the `amsmath` definition you should move the argument outside the `\mathchoice`.  You can move the `6mu` spacing and the typing of the word `mod` too this is the same in all cases.  As @egreg points out, the `\allowbreak` should be moved out of the `\mathchoice`; inside it has no effect.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\mod}[1]{\allowbreak
  \mathchoice
  {\if@display \mkern 18mu\else \mkern 5mu\fi}
  {\if@display \mkern 18mu\else \mkern 5mu\fi}
  {\mkern4mu}
  {\mkern4mu} {\operator@font mod} \mkern 6mu #1
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\(  5 \mod \mathfrak f \)

\begin{equation*}
  5 \mod \mathfrak f
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

In a way it is lucky it works as `#1` is just `\mathfrak` here; add `\tracingmacros=1` to see this.
The way the command is operating the argument is necessary at all, you could just define

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\mod}{\allowbreak
  \mathchoice
  {\if@display \mkern 18mu\else \mkern 5mu\fi}
  {\if@display \mkern 18mu\else \mkern 5mu\fi}
  {\mkern4mu}
  {\mkern4mu} {\operator@font mod} \mkern 6mu
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: `\allowbreak` should be before `\mathchoice`, because it has no effect otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for `\mathchoice` here, just of some arithmetic; however, I'd emphasize that the correct syntax for `\mod` and `\mathfrak` is

```
a\equiv b \mod{\mathfrak{p}}
```

It's true that with the standard definition `\mod \mathfrak p` seems to work, but it's just that: it *seems* to work.

TeX provides `\nonscript` to specify math glue or kern that's not added in subscripts or superscripts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\textwidth=.5\textwidth % just not to waste space

\begin{document}

\section*{Standard}

$a\equiv b\mod{\mathfrak{p}} + X_{a\equiv b\mod{\mathfrak{p}}}$
\[
a\equiv b\mod{\mathfrak{p}} + X_{a\equiv b\mod{\mathfrak{p}}}
\]

\section*{Modified}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\mod}[1]{%
  \allowbreak
  \nonscript\if@display \mkern 14mu \else \mkern 1mu \fi
  \mkern 4mu
  {\operator@font mod}
  \mkern 6mu
  #1
}
\makeatother

$a\equiv b\mod{\mathfrak{p}} + X_{a\equiv b\mod{\mathfrak{p}}}$
\[
a\equiv b\mod{\mathfrak{p}} + X_{a\equiv b\mod{\mathfrak{p}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very instructive, and I'll correct my bad syntax habits with respect to leaving out pairs of `{` and `}`. Since I'm still learning LaTeX, I have a question: you wrote that `\mod \mathfrak p` only *seems* to work; could you clarify what goes wrong when one writes this?

Comment: @justin When you write that, the argument to `\mod` is `\mathfrak`, It's just by chance that the implementation of `\mod` makes it work the same: you were exactly bitten by the fact that *your* implementation doesn't make it work. When a macro taking an argument is not followed by `{`, it takes as argument the first token it finds, otherwise it takes everything up to the matching `}`.