# What is \if@display used for in amsmath?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I noticed that in part of [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39221/removing-extra-space-with-pmod-command/39222?noredirect=1#comment620423_39222) where `\pod` is redefined using `\mathchoice`, the statement `\if@display`...`\else`...`\fi` is used for the first two options of `\mathchoice`. I was wondering: what does `@display` mean, and when is it necessary (or encouraged) to use the statement `\if@display`...`\else`...`\fi`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\if@display` is a single token, not `\if` `@display` it is defined and documented as follows in amsmath:

```
%    The straightforward \cs{ifinner} test to see if the current math
%    context is non-display, fails if, for instance, we are typesetting
%    a multiline display within an \cs{halign}, with the pieces going
%    into constructions like
%    \begin{verbatim}
%    $\displaystyle...$
%    \end{verbatim}
%    So we need a better test to find out if we are `in a display'. We
%    therefore create \cs{if@display}.
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newif\if@display
\everydisplay\@xp{\the\everydisplay \@displaytrue}
%    \end{macrocode}
```

Basically this is an internal construct in amsmath not intended for use elsewhere, although it can sometimes be used with care as an alternative to the usual `\mathchoice` construct.